# Image over image not working for gmail

Tags: html, image, gmail

I have the following snippet of code that goes through email into `GMAIL`:

```
<table width="800" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="" class="100p">

<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">

<img src="background.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; display:block;"/>

<a href="link.com">
<img src="mainimage.jpg" style="position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; display:block;" />
</a>

</div>
```

But when the code goes through gmail, it simply stacks the two one below the other. I followed the advice on [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjr_oL2qYjIAhUKLYgKHfWWCfE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1074914%2Fhtml-image-over-image&usg=AFQjCNEmxnTHvSF5XPow182xOe4tuHpwjQ) but nothing seems to be working to float the main over the background.

Please help!

Comment: Please show us your css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="800" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="" class="100p">
```

First off, **never** start a css *class* or *id* name with a number (100p)! This is generally a big no-no in any language.

Second, you are using a table, but you don't have any columns or rows. Why is that?